# Remove Junit from eclipse build path

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm trying to remove Junit from the build path a (plugin) project in Eclipse(I've refactored the tests into a separate Project.

Should be simple, but the remove button is greyed out for me:

[image]

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I havent used eclipse in a while, maybe removing junit project nature from the project? (Just guessing cannot check though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a Plugin project, you should maintain the build path via the manifest editor for the plugin (the same editor manipulates both `manifest.mf` and `plugin.xml`). That's where you declare the dependencies that the plugin has, which in turn automatically maintains the build path. There are a couple of ways of expressing a dependency, either as a *Required Plug-in* or as an *Imported Package*.

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: You are right, I'll accept and I'm going to edit to add a screenshot if you don't mind.